# How can I find the next/previous row in a database?

Tags: mysql

I am working on some PHP / mysql 5 web project involving a database table that uses not indexed GUID strings as its identifier for rows. So the rows of this product table look like this:

```
GUID                                   Name
936DA01F-9ABD-4d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8   Product 1
07c5bcdc-b3a6-482f-8556-bb04fae06538   Product 2
b7b39700-d0e2-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66   Product 3
```

The new requirement is, when I am on the details page of `Product 2`, this page should contain a previous link (pointing to `Product 1`) and a back link pointing to `Product 3`.

Finding `Product 2` is easy:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE GUID = "07c5bcdc-b3a6-482f-8556-bb04fae06538"
```

But how would I find the GUIDs of the previous and next products?

Remember: The product table has no auto-increment column and I cant add one easily as I am not in control over the database ...

**EDIT:**

The records are ordered by a timestamp column.

Comment: can you be explicit about what "next" and "previous" means?  Is the ordering implied by this ... by insertion time, lexicographical order of product name, some arbitrary user-defined order ...

Comment: @empraptor: good point, sorry I forgot to mention that. I checked and the data should be sorted in the same order as it is inserted. So, if product X is inserted before Y, then X is the previous of Y.

Comment: Relational databases as a general rule are unordered tables, unless you add artificial means (a timestamp column or identity) you can't normally reliably tell the order rows were inserted. In any case, why would the order the things were inserted be meaningful to an end user?

Comment: @JohnFx: Hm, you are probably right. I then will sort it by a timestamp column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused ....

Regarding the answer from Jeff;  If the product has no naming schema (random?) ***how are the products sorted in the output to the pages?***

If the output to the pages are sorted by timestamp only, then the answer from Jeff can be used with a small alteration of the where clause:

```
select guid from product
where timestamp < (select timestamp from product where name = 'Product 2')
order by timestamp desc limit 1;
```

and the other one:

```
select guid from product
where timestamp > (select timestamp from product where name = 'Product 2')
order by timestamp asc limit 1;
```

Or use the GUID from 'Product 2':

```
select guid from product
where timestamp < (select timestamp from product where GUID = guid_from_product2)
order by timestamp desc limit 1;
```

and the other one:

```
select guid from product
where timestamp > (select timestamp from product where guid = guid_from_product2)
order by timestamp asc limit 1;
```

Regards
     Sigersted

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's horrible.

Would something like this work?  This is assuming you sort the products by name.

If you're on the Product 2 page...

To get Product 1:

```
select guid from product where name < 'Product 2' order by name desc limit 1;
```

To get Product 3:

```
select guid from product where name > 'Product 2' order by name asc limit 1;
```

Note that Bad Things will happen if you have products with the same name.

Comment: Unfortunately the products have no naming schema, so this wont be an option. Yes, its really horrible.

Answer (score 0):

A row ID would help...

I found this link: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,25654,173160#msg-173160

```
set @a := 0;
select *, @a := @a+1 as rowid
from table
limit 10 ;
```

Comment: And that would only be valid if your sorting criteria is the insertion order (kudos to empraptor for being thorough)